# The underlying connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: http, windows-8, .net-4.5

I'm getting `The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly` error while executing the following code (windows 8, .net 4.5):

```
link = @"http://login.rutracker.org/forum/index.php";
_request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, link);
_request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Chrome/22.0.1229.94");
_request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html");
var content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
content.Add("login_username", name);
content.Add("login_password", "pass");
_request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);
_request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
_request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("deflate");
_response = await _client.GetAsync(_request.RequestUri);
return await _response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

My goal is to make request same as the following (log from `Fiddler` app):

```
POST /forum/login.php HTTP/1.1

Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*

Referer: http://rutracker.org/forum/index.php

Accept-Language: en-US

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 71

DNT: 1

Host: login.rutracker.org

Pragma: no-cache

Cookie: spylog_test=1

login_username=myusername&login_password=mypass&login=%C2%F5%EE%E4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was to forbid automatical request redirection:

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the:

```
_request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("gzip");
_request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("deflate");
```

as you are not sending gzipped content

Also, I would recommend you to look at what it is actually sent with your code with WireShak -  as I am sure `HttpRequestMessage` already append most of the headers you need.

Comment: I've tried various combinations of sent/not sent headers, including removing these headers, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the output you get with Fiddler by using your code?